# Can I add GeoExt or ArcGIS JS API to Openlayers + Dojo App?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoext, dojo

I've written a basic map app with Dojo and Openlayers (using titlebar , toggle buttons , checkbox tree and some more).
I've seen ArcGIS JS Api has nice tooltip / balloon and GeoExt has nice Legend Panel which I want to add both to my app.

ArcGIS looked a little bit complicated to add (it interrupted Dojo) so I passed it.
Can I add only GeoExt just for the legend Panel or will I need to choose either GeoExt or Dojo in my app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to use both GeoExt (or ExtJS for that matter) and Dojo.

Comment: This could have been better if you'd described how (or at least provided a link with some explanation). Your answer isn't really going to provide the user with much help if you don't provide something "actionable".

Comment: I've just figured out what was my probably (the order of the JS files.)